# VB6 Subscript out of range error at compile time

Tags: vb6

I am using a .Net DLL in VB6 project. When I try to call a DLL method from a VB6 class, the method is available with intellisense in VB6 Editor but when I compile I get "subscript out of range" error on the method call. I think that the "subscript out of range" is a runtime error, but here i got it at compile time.
Have you some ideas about the causes of this compile error?

Comment: Where is this code in your project? Is the Subscript our of Range error coming from a method with no parameters or is there some parameters being passed in? If there's parameters being passed in then the Subscript out of Range error could be due to one of them. I've run into similar issues in the past and I believe there's parts of the VB6 project that can get executed at compile time. You just need to handle the error in your code the same as you would if you were getting this error at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an array but exceeding its boundaries.
Hence SUBSCRIPT out of range

Comment: As mentioned in the description, it is a compile error and not a runtime error, VB6 is complaining of the method call. I think that the error is related to the number of parameters or the  the total length of method declaration because the exposed .Net method I try to call has more than 70 parameters (I am calling a legacy component).

Comment: Post your code which is relevant to the implementation/usage of the arrays and no doubt someone on the SO forums will find the issue. Somewhere possibly in a loop or a recursively subroutine, you are exceeding the boundaries of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the array range using **UBound** function:

VBScript UBound Function

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/vbscript_ubound_function.htm